# ROC-AUC is higher than accuracy score - what does this mean?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, roc, accuracy

I'm evaluating the performance of a trained neural network, and I'm getting the following stats:

> AUC-ROC: 0.91
>
> accuracy: 0.85

How should I interpret this result?

I'll add that the accuracy is a result of one-hotting the output and comparing it against the label, where as the AUC-ROC is calculated using the probabilistic (ie. range 0->1) output of a label. I'm not sure if it is correct to compare the metrics when doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall accuracy is measured at a specific point, and reflects your model's ability to place data into a proper category based on a specific threshold.

AUC more so reflects your model's ability to show a constant difference in data with different labels (i.e class A is generally higher/lower than class B), and doesn't explicitly depend upon the model's ability to correctly assign things to classes.